# Akka FSM: send msg to self in future on transition to next state

Tags: scala, akka, fsm

I am using an Akka FSM actor. A simplified version of my actor has two states: Idle and Processing. The actor receives a msg containing data, causing it to transition from Idle to Processing. The onTransition function kicks off a long running computation that uses the data and sends the processed data back to the actor:

```
def onTransition{
  case Idle -> Processing => future {
    longRunning(nextStateData)
  }.map{
    result => self ! result
  }
}
```

My main question is: assuming no event occurs that causes my actor to perform another state transition, are there any guarantees that I will not receive the processed data in the Idle state? If longRunning is not actually long running and finishes immediately, can I get the result before the transition is complete?

Is there a way to start the computation on entering the Processing state instead?

Side question: Is nextStateData a mutable variable? Should I not being using it in the future the way I am above?

**EDIT:**

The main point of my question is about what state the actor can receive the result msg in. After thinking about this, I am pretty sure that even if the computation finishes and the result msg is sent during the state transition, the actor will not pop the msg off its queue until after the transition is complete. Because of this, I can be assured that the actor will not get the result message in the Idle state.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why are you kicking off the future, especially if you are not planning on receiving any further messages?

Comment: nextStateData is actually a function, not a val or var.  That said, I also question the need for a future.  What exactly is your use case?

Comment: @agilesteel It will get more messages, and I am kicking off the future so that it can continue processing those messages while it does the computation in the background.  I meant to say that no event occurs to cause another state transition. I will edit it to try to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ryan I am currently using an actor handle a long running process.  It receives the data to process in a message, and then starts processing it in the background. When it is done, it sends the result to itself. Other actors can query it for the result. If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know, but I am mainly concerned about receiving the computed result when I am still in the Idle state, where the result has no meaning.

Comment: If you only have two states, I'd forgo the FSM and just use become/unbecome without a future.  You define two receive functions: one representing Idle state in which you receive work, one representing Processing.  I use this pattern and it works very well.